Automatic covariate labels in stargazer table
stargazer allows the user to specify covariate labels with the covariate.labels  argument, but this requires the user to know in advance the order of the covariates in the table. How can I reliably determine the order of the covariates in the table, without checking it manually?
To work with a reproducible example, suppose that I estimate three regressions on the iris dataset:
data(iris)
specifications = c(
  'Sepal.Length~Petal.Length',
  'Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length',
  'Sepal.Length~Petal.Length+Petal.Width'
)
fits = lapply(specifications, function(s) lm(s, data=iris))
stargazer(fits, type='text')

We can see that stargazer prints the Sepal.Width variable first, followed by Petal.Length, Petal.Width, and then the Constant. Based on this knowledge, we could supply an appropriate covariate.labels argument, knowing that we're not mis-labeling any of the covariates. But what if we want to do this automatically, without first manually checking the stargazer output? Can we supply the covariate.labels argument without knowing in advance the order of the covariates that stargazer will choose?
I might like to define my covariable labels just once, like this, and have the same labels used throughout the code:
variable_labels = data.frame(
  variable = c('Sepal.Length','Sepal.Width','Petal.Length','Petal.Width'),
  labels = c('sepal length','sepal width','petal length','petal width')
)

One approach would be to specify the order of the covariates in advance, and then use this order to set the covariate.labels argument. For example:
rhs_vars = unique(unlist(
  lapply(specifications, function(s) 
  strsplit(
    strsplit(s, '~', fixed=TRUE)[[1]][[2]],
    '+', fixed=TRUE)[[1]]))) # c("Petal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
stargazer(fits, type='text', order = rhs_vars)
stargazer(fits, type='text', order = rhs_vars, 
          covariate.labels = variable_labels$labels[
            match(rhs_vars,variable_labels$variable)]) # labels are ordered correctly

This works but is not very satisfactory to me. Does anyone have a better approach, perhaps by understanding the inner workings of stargazer? For example, will the order of the covariates match the order of the covariates in the underlying data.frame on which the models have been estimated (which is the iris data.frame in this example)?
